# Show git pairs in (oh-my-zsh) terminal

Tags: mac, terminal, git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have setup my (oh-my-zsh) terminal to display/indicate all sort of git stuff (on which branch, uncommited changes, etc.).

I believe that it comes from

```
plugins=(
  git
  ...
)
```

**Is it also possible to have it indicate who you are [pairing](https://github.com/pivotal-legacy/git_scripts) with?**

I tend to forget to change the pairs once it a while and it would be a big help if it was there.

Hope this mockup shows what I'm looking for:

```
~/Desktop master ✔                                                                        
▶ git pair js sp
user.name=Josh Susser & Sam Pierson
user.email=pair+jsusser+sam@pivotallabs.com

~/Desktop master ✔ (js sp)                                                                        
▶ git commit .
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/25811288

Comment: @Biswapriyo yes this is what I'm using. I'll update my question with an example of what I seek

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution

> .zshrc

```
[[ -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] && source ~/.p10k.zsh
source ~/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme

function prompt_git_user() {
    p10k segment -f 003 -i "$(git config user.name)"
  }

POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(
  newline
  git_user
)
```

---

Just be aware that the example overrules your settings for the right side of the prompt (where things like `command_execution_time` lives)